# IE appears to leak elements with ID's

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, memory, memory-leaks

I've been writing a few classes/coontrols using Mootools (1.4), and noticed a memory leak, after reading alot of forum pages I found the reasons for most of them, and also discovered sIEve.

While using sIEve I decided to ID all th elements I created to make it easier to see which where not being freed properly ie setting ids to "Header"+randomnumber. After testing and correcting the code using sIEve to aid me I noticed that the page was still loosing memory although sIEve now indicated that I was not orphaning any more elements.

I simplifed the page and continued to test, and this morning I found the leak.

I have reduced the page to a minimum to show the issue and removed any javascript includes.

The test page simply uses a timer to keep calling a function that replaced the contents of DIV with another DIV, no events, no styles, as basic as can be.

It would appear the the leak is caused by using unique (random) ID's for the DIV being replaced.  If I use the same ID each time it is replaced there is no memory leak. (also no leak in FF, not checked chrome ).

Can anyone tell me if I am doing something wrong, is it a know IE fault or even an unknown one.

Even if you dont have a solution I hope this might be of use.

**Just added to JSFiddle [IELeak](http://jsfiddle.net/cwQpQ/1/)**

**Updated JSFiddle using removeChild() [with removeChild](http://jsfiddle.net/cwQpQ/2/)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1    /DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Call the Plumber</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

var TestTimer;

function Test()
{    
    var rand = Math.random();
    var id = rand;              // this line will cause leak
//        var id = "SameID";            // this line will be fine
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "";   // in or out this line makes no difference
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "<div id=\""+id+"\">"+rand+"</div>";
}

function Hammer()
{
    for( var i=0; i<100; i++)
    {
        Test();
    }
}

function Run()
{
    TestTimer = setInterval( Hammer, 50 );
}

function Stop()
{
     clearInterval( TestTimer );
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="page">
    <div>
        <p>This will leak</p>
        <input type="button" onclick="Run()" value="Run" />
        <input type="button" onclick="Stop()" value = "Stop"/>
        <div id="content"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It probably keeps a reference to the node using the ID in a sort of dictionary. When you have random IDs, this will grow indefinitely. This seems like bad practice, and should not concern under normal usage? A workaround would be to instead of replacing the DIV, just replace the content within it.

Comment: Are you sure its a leak, and not the GC chillin' relaxin' all cool shootin' some Bball outside of the school?

Comment: Have you tried using `document.createElement` instead of innerHTML?

Comment: My original classes using mootools were using new Element not innerHTML, the above was a reduced test but i shall try and see if theres any difference

Comment: Chad, the application I will be using the classes on will be AJAX based so the main content DIV will be changed depending upon the users actions (menu selections) so all elements within that DIV will need to be released and replaced, could be graphs, tables, anything, but I agree I think IE is holding some sort of dictionary too, wondering if anyone knows if its accessible/prunable?

Comment: It will retain memory until it decides its time to garbage collect, if you left that running you should see the memory recovered after a while.  (Also the IDs in your test case are not valid in x/html 4 as they start with a number)

Comment: It sounds like you've got this under control, but I'm curious what happens if you use removeChild() to remove the item instead of simply setting the innerHTML to ""

Comment: @Alex, with the code as it is IE never releases the memory, even if the browser is sent to another page.

Comment: @Dave, i have just updated the JSFiddle to use removeChild and it now behaves differntly, memory goes up and down. I Thought initially it was working but still appears to leak.

Comment: All I can say is that I'm not surprised.  I coded a pretty complicated application in IE a couple of jobs ago (it was a locked down helpdesk, and that was my only option) and it leaked like a sieve.  I guess all you can do is to try to keep the number of unique IDs down.

Comment: @ Dave, I added the unique ID's for debugging my initial classes, I wont need then in the implementation I require so can work round the issue, just need to keep and ID'd elements to a minimum and reuse ID's on page/partial page reloads.  Most elements will be created programalically and references kept in the classes so IDs for those elements are required,  Its now more of a what is IE doing than anything else.

Comment: I've managed to reproduce the bug by simply changing the id of an existing element http://jsbin.com/ucuxef/3
This is just ridiculous.